# Adding Array To Mongo via AJAX Call and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document in a mongo database with information from a form, with all the form going into a field which is an array. At the moment I can't get it to update a document, only create a new one, but more pressingly I can't get the information from the form into the array.

Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const WorkoutSchema = new Schema({

    day: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    exercises: [
        {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: "Exercise type is required"
        },
        {
            name: String,
            trim: true,
            required: "Exercise name is required"
        },
        {
            duration: Number  
        },
        {
            weight: Number 
        },
        {
            reps: Number 
        },
        {

            sets: Number 
        },
        {
            duration: Number 
        },
        {
            distance: Number 
        }
    ]


  });

  const Workout = mongoose.model("Workout", WorkoutSchema);

  module.exports = Workout;
```

And here is my API route. I've included the results of console.logs below it so you can see the information that is getting passed.

```
app.put("/api/workouts/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log("api body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  console.log("body is " + typeof req.body);
  var body = JSON.stringify(req.body);

  // body = body.split("{")[1];
  // body = body.split("}")[0];
  // body = "["+body+"]";
  console.log(body);
  Workout.create({exercises: `${body}`})
    .then(Workout => {
      res.json(Workout);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err);
    });
});
```

api body: {"type":"resistance","name":"Test Press","weight":100,"sets":5,"reps":6,"duration":10}

body is object

{"type":"resistance","name":"Test Press","weight":100,"sets":5,"reps":6,"duration":10}

In the database I get exercises as an array with one element - the above object - instead of a series of key/value pairs. I've tried a lot of things, but this is as close as I get to what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a basic syntax error which came about because one of my keys was "type". The issue is in the syntax of the exercises array, the model should look like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const WorkoutSchema = new Schema({

    day: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    exercises: [{
        type: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: "Exercise type is required"
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: "Exercise name is required"
        },
        duration: {
            type: Number,
            required: "Duration is required"  
        },
        weight: {
            type: Number 
        },
        reps: {
            type: Number 
        },
        sets: {
            type: Number 
        },
        distance: {
            type: Number 
        }
    }]


  });

  const Workout = mongoose.model("Workout", WorkoutSchema);

  module.exports = Workout;
```